# Average of a calculated second average in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 tables : Appointments, Reviews, Review_ratings

Each review_ratings has a rating value. Each review has many review_ratings and finally, eeach appointment has many reviews.

What I am trying to do is to calculated the average of review_ratings per review, and then calculate the average of reviews total ratings and see if it is higher than a specific int.

Exemple:
Apointment id : 1, has 2 Reviews, each review has review_rating one of 4 and 3 and review rating number 2 of 5 and 5.

AVG(review_ratings) should return the average between average(5,5) and average(4,3) which is 3.5 then AVG(the_first_avg) should return average (3.5,5) which is 4.25.

My last tested query is :

```
if($minRating > 0){

                    $search->join('appointments','appointments.doctor_id','users.id')
                    ->join('reviews','reviews.appointment_id','appointments.id')
                    ->join('review_ratings','review_ratings.review_id','reviews.id')
                    ->addSelect(array('review_ratings.id',
                        DB::raw('AVG(review_ratings.rating) as review_ratings_count')
                     ))
                    ->addSelect(
                        DB::raw('AVG(review_ratings_count) as ratings_avg')
                     )
                    ->where('ratings_avg','>=',$minRating)
                    ;

                }
```

The error I'm getting is

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'review_ratings_count' in 'field
>   list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be much simpler that my code, and using AVG(name_of_column) rather than using the 'AS' value

```
->selectRaw('AVG(review_ratings.rating) as overall_rating')
            ->when($minRating > 0, function ($query) use($minRating)
                {
                    $query->havingRaw('AVG(review_ratings.rating) >= ?', [$minRating]);
                })
```